# reading a text file upto the maximum line size

Tags: perl

I have this input data in a text file

```
1-22-2
1-22-3
1-22-17-21-16-12-4
1-22-17-20-15-12-4
// .. a lot more lines (see revision)
22-17-20-15-12-4-6-8-10-13-18
22-17-21-16-12-4-6-7-9-5-19
22-17-20-15-12-4-6-7-9-5-19
22-17-21-16-12-15-20
22-17-20
22-17-21
22-17-20-15-12-16
```

I want the output file just same as input file but the designed program should read every input file line up to the maximum length. I want to make my file to be of fixed length.So that every line read should be up to the maximum length.

Comment: Perhaps you should say what you want to fill out your lines with then. Spaces? Pad right of left?

Comment: could i add zero after all my string lines upto 10 places in my file

Comment: It is simplest if you just edit your question and show what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
So, your code needs to do this:

Open the file1 for reading
Open another file2 for writing
Use a while loop to get each line
  Use the substr function to get only the first n characters of each line
  Write the modified line to file2
End Loop
Close file2
Close file1
```

Comment: i want the same ouput as my input file but when i use my output file next time it will read every line string to the maximum length string in file, whether there is nothing in string. Example 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3-4-5, 1-6-7-8-9-12-13. The maximum string here is 1-6-7-8-9-12-13 of length 7 so our program goes to every string whether it is short say of 4 but it will move forward upto the 7. So the ouput file will be easy to read for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in 2 one liners:

```
perl -lne "$l = $l < length $_ ? length $_ : $l; END { print qq{$l\n}}" file.txt
```

Should print the max characters.  Say it's 40.

```
perl -i.bak -lne "printf qq{%-40s\n}, $_" file.txt
```

Comment: Miller what you provided didn't work. Actually i want the same ouput as my input file but when i use my output file next time it will read every line string to the maximum length string in file, whether there is nothing in string. Example 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3-4-5, 1-6-7-8-9-12-13. The maximum string here is 1-6-7-8-9-12-13 of length 7 so our program goes to every string whether it is short say of 4 but it will move forward upto the 7.

Comment: If you want to clarify your specification, you should edit your post to include this info.  You haven't shown any real effort into solving this on your own, as if you had you would put more effort into making your post as detailed as possible.